# Problems installing gitlab with apache

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apache-httpd, nginx, gitlab

I am running a Linux mint (18.2) box. I have installed a LAMP stack that I use for some local development. I wanted to install GitLab to help manage my development cycle.

I was trying to install the omnibus package of GitLab following the instructions on the [official site](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu) and got stuck at the step:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.example.com" apt-get install gitlab-ee
```

Here I got an error saying " gitlab-ee package not found". So did an `apt-cache search` and and only found a `gitlab` package so installed that. It gave an error:

```
Setting up ruby-github-markup (1.3.3+dfsg-1build1) ...
Setting up ruby-gollum-lib (4.1.0-3) ...
Setting up gitlab (8.5.8+dfsg-5) ...
Creating/updating gitlab user account...
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/gitlab' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.
Creating runtime directories for gitlab...
Updating file permissions...
Configuring hostname and email...
Registering /etc/gitlab/gitlab.yml via ucf

Creating config file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.yml with new version
Registering /etc/gitlab/gitlab-debian.conf via ucf

Creating config file /etc/gitlab/gitlab-debian.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost with new version
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package gitlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't have nginx installed and would rather continue using apache along with my other sites instead of nginx. I found this site [Use Apache instead of built-in Nginx in GitLab CE](https://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/) but when I try `gitlab-ctl stop` I get a `gitlab-ctl: command not found` response.

Trying to re-install gives the following:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.natral.net" apt-get install gitlab
[sudo] password for natral: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gitlab is already the newest version (8.5.8+dfsg-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up gitlab (8.5.8+dfsg-5) ...
Creating/updating gitlab user account...
adduser: The user `gitlab' already exists.
Proceeding with existing gitlab user...
Creating runtime directories for gitlab...
Updating file permissions...
GITLAB_HOST=localhost 
Registering /etc/gitlab/gitlab.yml via ucf
Registering /etc/gitlab/gitlab-debian.conf via ucf

Creating config file /etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost with new version
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package gitlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```